# What is the font in Android's ActionBar?

Tags: android, fonts

What font is used by default, in the holo Android ActionBar?

I've only been able to find answers on how to change the font, but not what the default font is.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml.

Comment: as side note check this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Typeface.java may help

Answer (score 1):

On API Level 14+, the default font face for everything is [Roboto](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html). On API Level 13 and below, the default font face for everything is Droid Sans.

Conceivably, that could be changed by device manufacturers, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set any font programmatically then it will consider your device's font settings and set that for your actionbar.